# Why reduce number of short contracts to reduce beta, and take long positions to increase it?

Tags: portfolio, hedging, beta

My question is about chapter 3 in the ninth edition of "Options, futures and other derivatives" by John C. Hull, subchapter 5 under the heading "Changing the Beta of a Portfolio".

In the final paragraph, they explain how one can reduce the Beta of a portfolio by reducing the number of short contracts proportional to the reduction of the Beta (e.g. if the Beta is reduced by 0.5 times the Beta, then the amount of short contracts is reduced by 0.5 times the amount of short contracts),
and by taking a long position using the same method, in order to increase the Beta.

I have some questions about this: first, how d you know that initially the portfolio holds shorted futures contracts? Is this always the case when calculating the amount of contracts required for a hedge/do they assume this in the chapter? And why does taking less short contracts reduce the Beta, but taking additional long contracts increase it?
Is the first in order to reduce the total excess return and the second it in order to offset the sensitive change?

I believe my thinking is in the right direction but I tend to question it because I'm working with beginner's knowledge and understanding and I want to make sure I'm not mixing up or misunderstanding concepts, so far it's been hard to grasp.

Comment: I don't have the book in front of me, but presumably in an earlier section they have explained how to *remove all the beta* also known as *hedging the beta risk* or (similar terms with the word hedge in it) from a portfolio. And they showed how to calculate the number of index futures contracts you have to short to do this. *Now they are just saying: what if you want to remove only half the beta risk? Then you just short half the number of contracts we calculated earlier, so we don't have to explain again, you already know how to do this.*

Comment: ...and similarly in the other direction: if you want to *double the beta risk* you could go **long** the same number of contracts that you previously calculated you need to **short** to hedge the market risk. These are all variations of the same idea that they have explained (and you may have missed) earlier in the text.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful! I don't think they explicitly stated the beta risk was eliminated by hedging but I suppose this was implied, eithe rway the way you explained it made it much clearer. <3